# UISegmented Control selects multiple segments at once

Tags: ios, objective-c, uisegmentedcontrol

I have a UISegmented Control with three segments 'Red,'Green','Blue'. I want to change the circle of the colour when a user taps the segment but if a user first touches red and then green, the red segment is still highlighted. How do I allow only one segmented to be selected?

Answer (score 0):

The behavior that you are describing is not the default behavior for UISegmentedControl. In fact, segmented controls are designed to only have one segment selected at once, and UIKit has no configuration for multiple select. I am unsure why you are encountering this behavior, but your best bet would be to trace the connected actions/outlets for your segmented control and see if you are setting the selected segment anywhere in your code. You could even rebuild this part of the UI (and associated IBActions) from scratch to be sure that you are implementing it properly to get your desired function. Good luck!

Comment: huh? multiple select UISegmentedControl?

Comment: I apologize, I was getting it mixed up with OS X UI elements. As far as I can tell, the behavior you are experiencing isn't "possible" with UIKit. I updated my answer with some suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you configured the selection images incorrectly. A UISegmentedControl cannot have a multiple selection, so you must be doing something wrong that makes it *look* like there's a multiple selection.